# DBF SQL Update records returned from a Select with join

Tags: sql, dbf, dbase

I admit I must be missing something here. I have some DBF tables and am using DBF Commander to query / update. I have a fairly simple select query that returns the desired records.

```
    Select * FROM TODO as a 
    JOIN job as b on a.td_job = b.j_job 
    where td_asgndto = 'GEORGE' 
      and td_status <> 'COMPLETED'
```

All I want to do is update the TODO table and set a.td_status = 'COMPLETED' for the records returned on the above select.

If I run this UPDATE:

```
    UPDATE TODO 
       Set td_status = 'COMPLETED' 
    FROM TODO as a 
    JOIN job as b on a.td_job = b.j_job 
    where a.td_asgndto = 'GEORGE' 
      and a.td_status <> 'COMPLETED'
```

It sets td_status = 'COMPLETED' for EVERY record in TODO.

Is there a simple answer to this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (UPDATE FROM isn't ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Comment: @jarlh dBASE is the dbms

Comment: May be, td_status  isNULL, then td_status <> 'COMPLETED' always ``true``. What do you need a JOIN for?  The data from the second table is not used.

Comment: @ValNik I need the join to determine which records to update. The Select query returns the correct records so there's no problem with td_status being Null.